# Custom module model getCollection gives error

Tags: magento-1.9, resource-model, getmodel

I have created a custom admin module and necessary assets. When I call getCollection using created model its giving me error

```
Warning: include(Company\Module\Model\Resource\Event\Collection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\wamp\www\domain\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

#0 C:\wamp\www\domain\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Fouraxi...', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\cra...', 93, Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\domain\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload(Company...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Company...')
#4 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1346): class_exists('Company...')
#5 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('Module_res...', Object(Company_Module_Model_Resource_Event))
#6 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('Module/eve...', Object(Company_Module_Model_Resource_Event))
#7 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('Module/eve...', Object(Company_Module_Model_Resource_Event))
#8 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#9 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\local\Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Print\Grid.php(7): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#10 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(626): Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Print_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#12 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#13 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#15 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#16 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid\container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#17 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\wamp\\www\\cra...')
#18 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#19 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#23 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#25 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#27 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#28 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\wamp\\www\\cra...')
#29 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#30 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#31 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#32 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#34 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#35 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\local\Company\Module\controllers\Adminhtml\ModuleController.php(22): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#36 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Company_Module_Adminhtml_ModuleController->viewAction()
#37 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#38 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#39 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#40 C:\wamp\www\domain\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#41 C:\wamp\www\domain\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#42 {main}
```

config.xml

```
<models>
            <Module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Module_resource</resourceModel>
            </Module>
            <Module_resource>
                <class>Company_Module_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <event>
                        <table>Module_event_data</table>
                    </event>
                    <event_registrant>
                        <table>Module_event_registrant</table>
                    </event_registrant>
                </entities>
            </Module_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <Module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Module</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </Module_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <Module>
                <class>Company_Module_Block</class>
            </Module>
        </blocks>
```

Grid Block

```
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Print_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('Module/event')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('order_id', array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'index'=>'name',
            'header'=>$this->__('Print Id')
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**Edit:::**

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Model_Resource_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Module/event');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you create this file `Fouraxissolutions\Casestation\Model\Resource\Event\Collection.php`

Comment: No. Is it necessary to create Collection.php  when calling getCollection()?

Comment: yes bro when you call `casestation/event` this will get collection from this file `Spacename/Casestation/Model/Resource/Event/Collection.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with missing the collection file

`Module\Name\Model\Resource\Event\Collection.php`

you need to create the collection file. because

when you call `module/event` this will get collection from this file `Spacename/module/Model/Resource/Event/Collection.php`

Comment: I created the collection.php file. Error is gone. But still its not showing grid. Only shows blank screen. Updated the question. Added collection.php file I created

Comment: @Dushan follow this for creating the Model collection http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/